# notification data null pointer exception while opening the activity

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am receiving notification successfully.But my need is when I click in the notification that should move to that particular activity with some data. while starting the activity raise null pointer exception error.

Firebase fuction :
// my package name is com.google.tho.temp

```
 const token_id = result.val();
      const payload = {
        notification: {
        title: `${from_user_id} id_of my`,
        body: `${userName} send order request`,
        icon: "default",
        sound : "default",
         click_action : "com.google.tho.TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
       },
       data : {
         from_user : from_user_id
       }
      };
```

Manifest file :

```
<activity
        android:name=".Open profile"
        android:label="Openpro"
        android:parentActivityName=".Received_orders">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.tho.TARGET_NOTIFICATION"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Notification receiver class :

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String noti_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String noti_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String click_Action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user").toString();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setContentTitle(noti_title)
                        .setContentText(noti_message);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_Action);
        resultIntent.putExtra("signal",from_user_id);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Open profile.class :

```
  signal = getIntent().getStringExtra("signal").toString().trim();
```

Comment: show your log..

Comment: In your manifest.xml, you wrote wrong action name "com.google.tho.TARGET_NOTIFICATION". Fix the "tho" -> "the".

Comment: I used click_action : "com.google.tho.TARGET_NOTIFICATION" in firebase function also as same.

Comment: @ Shararti KAKA I have added log below